# Command recall (up/down arrow) is not working with Ubuntu Desktop 20/04 running as kvm container

Tags: command-line, bash

The title says it all.  I am using a .bashrc similar to what's running on my desktop.  I've googled for an answer but I came up empty.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: hi, is it only  as the login shell of your non-root user?

Comment: It doesn't work for root either.  I just checked, it's system wide, noit limited to bash.  It doesn't work in vi either.  All the other positioning keys work fine, down arrow, right, left, pageup, pagedown, home, end.  It's just the up arrow that fails.

Comment: I ran xev.  Up arrow doesn't produce anything.  On the host it works fine.  Not on the container.

Answer (score 0):

It was a setting in my xmodmap.  I removed it and all is well.
Jim

Comment: More details are required. What setting? How did you remove it? This info is for future users who may have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather specific to my environment.  The file, .Xmodmap, I have set up to allow me to easily construct special characters, like ñ, Ø, ¢ etc. There was a
line in it that referenced the up arrow.  I don't recall the exact format of the line since I've deleted it.  The command that I use to make the changes is xmodmap .Xmodmap.  Here is my .Xmodmap file:

```
clear Lock
keycode 0x42 =  Multi_key       Mode_switch
```

This is on the host not the container.  I composed this thing years ago and don't have a clue what the remove line was supposed to do.

Hope that helps,
Jim.